# GridView Images are changing postion when scrolling

Tags: android

I'm loading images from server along with a text and displaying them in a gridview, I'm using a base adapter to fill the grid. Here is the code of the adapter:

```
   package com.erc.test;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class CustomGrid2 extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        private final ArrayList<String> web;
        private final ArrayList<String> Imageid;
          public CustomGrid2(Context c,ArrayList<String> web, ArrayList<String> imageId ) {
              mContext = c;
              this.Imageid = imageId;
              this.web = web;
          }

          public void removeItem(int position){
              web.remove(position);
              Imageid.remove(position);
              notifyDataSetChanged();
         }


          public void clearitems(){
              web.clear();
              Imageid.clear();
              notifyDataSetChanged();
         }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return web.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /////////////////////////////////// 
            View grid;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
                grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);
            } else {
                grid = (View) convertView;
            }
            TextView text = (TextView)grid.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            text.setText(web.get(position));
            RoundedImageView image = (RoundedImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            image.setPlaceholderImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            image.setImageUrl(Imageid.get(position));
          //  image.setImageDrawable();
            return grid;
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////     


        }
    }
```

In my main class I'm doing the following :

```
package com.erc.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Categories extends Activity {
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpPost httppost;
    GridView grid;
    ProgressBar pb;
    CustomGrid2 adapter;
       Drawable[] dd=null;
        ArrayList<String> actorsList;
        ArrayList<String> title;
        JSONArray jarray;
    ArrayList<String> namearray= new ArrayList<String>();    
    ArrayList<Drawable> imagearray= new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.categories);

        grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
         actorsList = new ArrayList<String>();
           title = new ArrayList<String>();
        new ProgressTask().execute();

    }


    class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://www.page.com/folder/file.php?userid=2&client=android&sandbox=0&language=en&format=json");
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                     jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("categories");


                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
            //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e1.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              // e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            try
            {
              for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                  //  Actors actor = new Actors();
                    actorsList.add(object.getString("picture").replace("https","http"));
                    title.add(object.getString("name"));}
              }         
                   catch(Exception ex)
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
              //      Log.d("title is",object.getString("image"));

//                  adapter = new CustomGrid2(MainActivity.this, title, actorsList);
            //  grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                 //   actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                 //   actorsList.add(actor);



            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter = new CustomGrid2(Categories.this, title, actorsList);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


//          grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
//
//              @Override
//              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
//                      int arg2, long arg3) {
//                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              String id=String.valueOf(arg2+1);
//              String category_name=namearray.get(arg2);
//              Intent intent = new Intent(Categories.this, Subcategories.class);
//              Bundle b = new Bundle();
//              b.putString("ID",id); //Your id
//              b.putString("Name",category_name);
//              intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
//              startActivity(intent);
//              
//              }
//          });




        }
    }

//    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
//      {
//
//
//      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
//      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//      String line = null;
//      try
//      {
//
//      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//        sb.append(line + "\n");
//      }
//      }catch(IOException e)
//      {
//
//      }
//      finally
//      {
//          try{
//              is.close();
//          }catch(IOException e)
//          {
//              
//          }
//          }return sb.toString();
//
//
//
//      }

}
```

And in the following class I give the imageview a circular shape and I download the image from url:

```
package com.erc.test;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;



    public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {
        private Drawable placeholder, image;

        public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

            if (drawable == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
                return; 
            }
            Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
            Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();


            Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
            canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);

        }

         public void setPlaceholderImage(Drawable drawable) {
                placeholder = drawable;
                if (image == null) {
                    setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }
            }
            public void setPlaceholderImage(int resid) {
                placeholder = getResources().getDrawable(resid);
                if (image == null) {
                    setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }
            }

            public void setImageUrl(String url) {
                DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();  
                task.execute(url);
            }

            private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String url = params[0];
                    try {
                        URLConnection conn = (new URL(url)).openConnection();
                        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50); 
                        int current = 0;
                        while ((current=bis.read()) != -1) {
                            baf.append((byte)current);
                        }

                        byte[] imageData = baf.toByteArray();
                        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    image = new BitmapDrawable(result);
                    if (image != null) {
                        setImageDrawable(image);
                    }
                }



            }

            public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
                Bitmap sbmp;
                if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
                    sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
                else
                    sbmp = bmp;
                Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
                        sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

                final int color = 0xffa19774;
                final Paint paint = new Paint();
                final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
                paint.setDither(true);
                canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
                paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
                canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
                        sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
                canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


                        return output;
            }
        }
```

The problem is when I scroll the grid the images change position, any help please ?

Comment: How are you using this class in your main. What method(s) call this?

Comment: I've updated my answer please check it

Comment: If you scroll the list the old image will remain set on the ImageView because attempting to set a placeholder on it will  fail as the *image* field is not null. So you'll see the old image for that ImageView until the current task finishes retrieving the proper image. What you're doing is not very efficient, you should use one of the image handling libraries out there, like Picasso, Universal image loader etc.